# Tkinter root.destroy delayed after time.sleep

Tags: python, tkinter, time

After destroying a Tkinter window I put a `time.sleep`, however it first waits, then destroys the window, instead of first destroying then waiting

```py
root.destroy()
time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue in my Windows 7 with Python 3.8.13.  The window is closed before the sleep.

Comment: Your assumption is incorrect. The window object _is_ destroyed. It's just that tkinter can't update the display because the program is sleeping.

Comment: @BryanOakley I actually solved the problem by adding a root.update() after the root.destroy()

Comment: Yes, that's one way to solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I tried to recreate an issue using a basic program, but there is no way I would understand this issue: it's *probably* made up, not completely sure. Tried on different devices with different versions.
(If it is not made up, I'm sorry for blaming you.)

I tried on:
Windows 10 latest build, Python 3.10.x: no issues
Windows 7, Python 3.8.5: no issues

```py
def destroy_it():
    root.destroy()

button = Button(root, text="Exit", command=destroy_it)
button.pack()
```

> That one basic program is here: https://dpaste.com/6PTEPTM6K (lasts for one year)